# I am not able to capture user Media stream inside meteor package

Tags: meteor, meteor-packages, rtcmulticonnection

I am able to capture User media inside the meteor project using `RTCmulticonnection` library.
But I want to create a meteor package. When I try to use my meteor package inside different project it's giving me an error.

[when I try to access media stream it giving me an error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZTz0.png)

Comment: Please add the code of the package or a link. The error seems to be related to something missing in your package.

Comment: do we have to add browser policy inside meteor package so that i can get access to webcam at the moment. this is throwing error occurring because code is not able to detect local media stream